# How to install Windows 98 with ACPI enabled from Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, windows-98

I have a Windows 98 SE ISO file and want to install it with ACPI enabled. i found this https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=9918

I always mount ISO file in Virtualbox.
however i don't really know how to copy these files in Virtualbox C folder and how to install Windows using command line switches... how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170785-virtualbox-windows-98se-step-by-step/

1. Boot the ISO to Start Windows 98 Setup and configure the hard drive (enable large disk support)
2. Start computer with CD-ROM support then enter the following commands

> ```
> D:
> CD Win98
> Format C: /V:Win98se
> Setup /p j
> ```

98SE was bootable media so it should work quite well - just so long as you make sure the right VirtualBox machine configuration is set.

Comment: I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Ok it Worked fine.

Comment: works only with 4.* series at least on my pc